# Enabling authentication realm in jetty 8

Tags: authentication, jetty, restful-authentication, jetty-8

I tried to follow [the offical tutorial](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Realms) to enable MD5 authentication for my only web-app running on jetty. Nginx manages ssl and redirects to jetty

I placed

```
   <Call name="addBean">
      <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService">
          <Set name="name">My Realm</Set>
          <Set name="config"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/etc/realm.properties</Set>
          <Set name="refreshInterval">0</Set>
        </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>
```

In `jetty.xml`, and the content of realm.properties are :

```
test: MD5:098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6,user
```

In the tutorial they do not tell where to assign the realm to a context so I don't know where to place this :

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
   <Get name="securityHandler">
       <Set name="realmName">My Realm</Set>
   </Get>
</Configure>
```

I tried to put in in `jetty-context.xml`, and in `web.xml`, but it is still not working. I receive a 502 (bad gateway) when I place this in `jetty.xml`, in the other cases I get a normal json result from the web service (Shouldn't I get a 503 - not authorized ?)

Answer (score 2):

A "Context XML File" (as outlined in [Configuring Security Realms](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Realms)) refers [Webapp deployment using the ContextProvider](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/ContextDeployer) (enabled by default on jetty-distribution).

This deploys webapps by using a XML file, usually found in `${jetty.home}/contexts/` with a description of where that webapp is located on disk, and some details on how you want that webapp deployed.

You can also use the [`WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml`](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Reference/jetty-web.xml) to embed this Context configuration within your WAR file.